# Sed replace with first characters in line

Tags: bash, sed

I'm a bit stuck on a sed replace problem. I have a tab separated file, that looks something like this:

```
stuff1 \t names names names
stuff2 \t \t names names names
stuff3 \t \t names names names
stuff4 \t names names names
```

What I would like to do is replace the double-tabs in a way, that it would insert the first word between them. Like this:

```
stuff2 \t stuff2 \t names names names
stuff3 \t stuff3 \t names names names
```

What I tried was

```
sed 's/\t\t/\t(.*\t\t\)\t/'
```

but when I try to replace it with the escape group, it takes it literally and changes every occurence of

```
\t\t
```

to

```
\t(.*\t\t\)\t
```

Is there a way to "escape the escape group"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match them like this:

```
$ sed -r 's/^(\S+)\t\t/\1\t\1\t/g' file
stuff1  names names names
stuff2  stuff2  names names names
stuff3  stuff3  names names names
stuff4  names names names
```

This is:

- `s/find/replacement/g`
  the full expression to find `find` and replace it with `replacement` `g`lobally.
- `^(\S+)\t\t`
  match the beginning of the line followed by a word (you could also say `[^\t]*`). Then, match two tabs.
- `\1\t\1\t`
  replace this with the captured match followed by a tab, and then again.
- `-r`
  this `sed` flag is used to have extended regexp that allow you to catch a group with just `(...)` instead of `\(...\)`.

---

By the way, to me, the output of your command is:

```
$ sed 's/\t\t/\t(.*\t\t\)\t/' file
stuff1  names names names
stuff2  (.*     )   names names names
stuff3  (.*     )   names names names
stuff4  names names names
```

Since you are using `.*` in the replacement part, so it is taken literally and not as a regular expression.